# phpexcel autofilter for particular cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to make `columns` with auto-filter drop down in downloaded excel. I am using `phpexcel` library here is my code snippet for `autofilter`

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter('A1:AQ1');
```

By using above code snippet I can able to set range for A to AQ column but I want to set my `dropdown` for only B and D column.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To apply a filter expression to an autoFilter range, you first need to identify which column you're going to be applying this filter to.

```
$autoFilter = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getAutoFilter();
$columnFilter = $autoFilter->getColumn('C');
```

This returns an autoFilter column object, and you can then apply filter expressions to that column.

Comment: Are you sure work in phpexcel? (seems like he use PHPEXCEL not PHPspreadsheet)

Comment: Yes, it should work. PHPSpreadsheet is the newest version of PHPExcel, PHP Excel has not be maintained for years , its direct successor is PhpSpreadsheet

Comment: yes i know, i use both. More function are deprecated, that's why i ask you that.